# Jquery Globalize setup using plain javascript - uncaught error

Tags: jquery-globalize

I am trying to setup jquery globalize using the js/json setup suggested (for date module), using a javascript example suggested [here](https://github.com/jquery/globalize/tree/master/examples/plain-javascript).
In this code I am trying to set it up and the use it to format the jquery-ui datepicker:

```
(function () {

$(function () {
    $.when(
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/cldr-json/cldr-core-master/supplemental/likelySubtags.json"),
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/cldr-json/cldr-numbers-modern-master/main/en/numbers.json"),
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/cldr-json/cldr-core-master/supplemental/numberingSystems.json"),
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/cldr-json/cldr-dates-modern-master/main/en/ca-gregorian.json"),
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/cldr-json/cldr-dates-full-master/main/en/timeZoneNames.json"),
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/cldr-json/cldr-core-master/supplemental/timeData.json"),
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/cldr-json/cldr-core-master/supplemental/weekData.json")
    ).then(function () {

        // Normalize $.get results, we only need the JSON, not the request statuses.
        return [].slice.apply(arguments, [0]).map(function (result) {
            return result[0];
        });

    }).then(Globalize.load).then(function () {

        var culture = "en";
        Globalize(culture);
        $("input.datepicker").datepicker({
            prevText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
            nextText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
            dateFormat: Globalize.dateFormatter({ date: "short" })
        });
    });
});})();
```

And the error I get is

> E_DEFAULT_LOCALE_NOT_DEFINED: Default locale has not been defined. in globalize.js @ line 105

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you read this? https://github.com/jquery/globalize/blob/master/doc/error/e-default-locale-not-defined.md

Comment: Yes, I have already. I tried both "Globalize(culture)" and "Globalize.locale(culture)" but I get the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used same code and had same error. Instead of:

```
    var culture = "en";
    Globalize(culture);
    $("input.datepicker").datepicker({
        prevText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
        nextText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
        dateFormat: Globalize.dateFormatter({ date: "short" })
    });
```

I just had: Globalize.locale("en"); and that fixed it.

- Make sure your function is called
- Make sure all your json objects are fetched

Comment: People might find this helpful for the 1.* globalize version as some functions now have been replaced/removed.: https://github.com/jquery/globalize/blob/master/doc/migrating-from-0.x.md

Comment: Yeap. `Globalize.locale("en")` sets the default locale for the static methods (i.e., `Globalize.<fn>`); and `var en = Globalize("en")` creates the instance for the instance methods (i.e., `en.<fn>`).