# Using Jquery Globalize with MVC 5

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-globalize

I am trying to use the MVC unobstrusive validation with jquery globalize plugin in MVC5 (in conjunction with the package [jquery-validate-globalize](https://github.com/johnnyreilly/jquery-validation-globalize)). For learning purposes I started a demo project as per [here](https://johnnyreilly.github.io/jQuery.Validation.Unobtrusive.Native/AdvancedDemo/Globalize.html), but it fails to run with globalize (it works on default Microsoft unobstrusive validation). The model is very simple:

```
public class GlobalizeModel
{
    [Range(10.5D, 20.3D)]
    public decimal Double { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime? DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

I try to initiate Globalize as follows at the bottom of the _Layout page (the view is minimal with 2 input only): (I get list of necessary files from https://johnnyreilly.github.io/globalize-so-what-cha-want/)

```
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

<!--cldr scripts-->
<script src="~/Scripts/cldr.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/cldr/event.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/cldr/supplemental.js"></script>
<!--globalize scripts-->
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/number.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/date.js"></script>
<!--jquery globalize-->
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.js"></script>


<script>

    $.when(
        $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/likelySubtags.json"),
        $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/main/en/numbers.json"),
        $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/numberingSystems.json"),
        $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/main/en/ca-gregorian.json"),
        $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/main/en/timeZoneNames.json"),
        $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/timeData.json"),
        $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/weekData.json"),
        $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/main/tr/numbers.json"),
        $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/main/tr/ca-gregorian.json"),
        $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/main/tr/timeZoneNames.json"),
        console.log("JSONs loaded")
        ).then(function () {
            console.log("start slicing");
            return [].slice.apply(arguments, [0]).map(function (result) {
                console.log("slicing done");
                return result[0];
            });
        }).then(Globalize.load).then(function () {
            Globalize.locale("en");
            console.log("Locale set to en");
        }).then(console.log("LOADED EVERYTHING"));


</script>
```

But when I run the page, I only see the console logs `JSOns loaded` and `LOADED EVERYTHING`. Moreover, when I try a client side validation by typing anything in the number textbox (and of course when the focus is lost), I get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: E_DEFAULT_LOCALE_NOT_DEFINED: Default locale has not been defined.
```

This post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32753888/jquery-globalize-setup-using-plain-javascript-uncaught-error) is similar, and I tried to check the things listed there. I think my JSON objects are not fetched, but I am not good aj JS so I am not sure on that. I added the following items to web.config to see if this is something related with file serving, with no avail:

```
<system.webServer>
 <staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".json"/>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
 </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

The culture is set to auto in web.config as follows:

```
<system.web>
  <globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" />
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
</system.web>
```

You can see `Scripts` folder structure in here:

[image: You can see <code>Scripts</code> folder structure in here]

So, what is the problem here? How can I make this thing work?

Comment: Did you ever find out what was happening? I think console.log("JSONs loaded") is interfering with the slicing function.

Comment: No; I was not able to solve it so I decided to not to use `globalize`. In the actual project, I disabled client side validation and relied on server validation in culture sensitive views (for example ones including decimal input). The reason behind this decision was I spent too much time on this with no avail, and there were a lot of things waiting to be done. Maybe I will revisit this issue in the future hoping globalization technology advances in the meantime.  P.S. The problem persisted without `console.log("JSONs loaded")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently ran into the same problem, trying to add I18n to an MVC5 web app. After several days of research and partly using your code as base, I found some things that helped me implement it.

My Solution:
In a separate project, I added decimal and DateTime properties to the ApplicationUser class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public DateTime birthdate { get; set; }
    public decimal balance { get; set; }
}
```

I also modified the RegisterViewModel to accept those properties, as follows:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime birthdate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal balance { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I set the culture in a base controller, from which other controllers inherit:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        string[] cultures = { "es-CL", "es-GT", "en-US" };
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultures[1]);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

        return base.BeginExecuteCore(callback, state);
    }
}
```

That's just for testing purposes, not the way I fetch culture in the real app.

My file structure is the same as yours and I didn't modify the web.config file.

I also used [this](http://johnnyreilly.github.io/globalize-so-what-cha-want/#/?currency=false&date=true&message=false&number=true&plural=true&relativeTime=true&unit=false) link for dependencies. But then I modified a few things in the scripts section of Register.cshtml:

```
<!-- CLDR -->
<script src="~/Scripts/cldr.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/cldr/event.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/cldr/supplemental.js"></script>
<!-- Globalize -->
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/number.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/date.js"></script>
<!-- $ validate -->
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.js"></script>
<!-- fetch files -->
<script>
    $.when(
        $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/likelySubtags.json"),
        $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/main/en/numbers.json"),
        $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/numberingSystems.json"),
        $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/main/en/ca-gregorian.json"),
        $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/main/en/timeZoneNames.json"),
        $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/timeData.json"),
        $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/weekData.json"),
        $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/main/tr/numbers.json"),
        $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/main/tr/ca-gregorian.json"),
        $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/main/tr/timeZoneNames.json"),
        ).then(function () {
            console.log("start slicing");
            return [].slice.apply(arguments, [0]).map(function (result) {
                console.log("slicing done");
                return result[0];
            });
        }).then(Globalize.load).then(function () {
            Globalize.locale("en");
            console.log("Locale set to en");
        }).then(console.log("LOADED EVERYTHING"));
</script>
```

The _Layout view scripts weren't modified at all, and I had no problem with the console logs.

That's all, it worked out for me, and as it's a very similar case, I hope it works for you too.

Comment: Thank you! I will try your recommendations once I have time and see if it works.

Comment: I just removed the console.log("JSONs loaded") line that caused the solution to crash.