# E_INVALID_PAR_TYPE is triggered during the page load (cldr, globalize)

Tags: globalize, jquery-globalize, cldr

We are trying to use [cldr](https://github.com/rxaviers/cldrjs)/[globalize](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize), unfortunately, an error is triggered during the load of the page.

Debugging the code does not help at all, **I can't figure out which input field generates the issue**

Do you need further info? Do you need more code? Just let me know

---

[image: E_INVALID_PAR_TYPE: {"expected":"Plain Object","name":"json","value":null}]

**JavaScript, load cldr data, set locale to 'en'**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863853/using-jquery-globalize-with-mvc-5
  // download json files on https://github.com/unicode-cldr?page=2
  // how to setup globalize, cldr and json data: http://johnnyreilly.github.io/globalize-so-what-cha-want

  var locale = 'en'; // TODO: manage the localization based on user preferences (browser)

  // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586551/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-validation-with-different-culture
  $.when(
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/plugins/cldr-core-30.0.2/supplemental/likelySubtags.json"),
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/plugins/cldr-numbers-full-30.0.2/main/" + locale + "/numbers.json"),
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/plugins/cldr-core-30.0.2/supplemental/numberingSystems.json"),
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/plugins/cldr-core-30.0.2/supplemental/plurals.json"),
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/plugins/cldr-core-30.0.2/supplemental/ordinals.json"),
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/plugins/cldr-numbers-full-30.0.2/main/" + locale + "/currencies.json"),
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/plugins/cldr-core-30.0.2/supplemental/currencyData.json"),
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/plugins/cldr-dates-full-30.0.2/main/" + locale + "/ca-gregorian.json"),
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/plugins/cldr-dates-full-30.0.2/main/" + locale + "/timeZoneNames.json"),
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/plugins/cldr-core-30.0.2/supplemental/timeData.json"),
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/plugins/cldr-core-30.0.2/supplemental/weekData.json"),
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/plugins/cldr-dates-full-30.0.2/main/" + locale + "/dateFields.json"),
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/plugins/cldr-units-full-30.0.2/main/" + locale + "/units.json"),
      console.log("JSONs loaded")
      ).then(function () {
        console.log("start slicing");
        return [].slice.apply(arguments, [0]).map(function (result) {
          console.log("slicing done");
          return (typeof result === 'undefined' ? null : result[0]);
        });
      }).then(Globalize.load).then(function () {
        Globalize.locale(locale);
        console.log("Locale set to " + locale);
      }).then(console.log("LOADED EVERYTHING"));


});
```

**HTML , load the javascripts**

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>StratEx | Project management</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE">
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="/Scripts/plugins/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="/Content/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="/Content/bootstrap-3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="/Content/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="/Content/themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script type="application/javascript" async="" defer="" src="https://by2.uservoice.com/t2/ID/web/ID/track.js?_=TIMESTAMP&amp;s=1&amp;c=__uvSessionData0&amp;d=HASH"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="//widget.uservoice.com/CODE.js"></script><script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
  <script
    src="/Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/cldrjs-0.4.7/dist/cldr.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/cldrjs-0.4.7/dist/cldr/event.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/cldrjs-0.4.7/dist/cldr/supplemental.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/globalize-1.1.2/dist/globalize.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/globalize-1.1.2/dist/globalize/number.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/globalize-1.1.2/dist/globalize/plural.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/globalize-1.1.2/dist/globalize/message.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/globalize-1.1.2/dist/globalize/currency.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/globalize-1.1.2/dist/globalize/date.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/globalize-1.1.2/dist/globalize/relative-time.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/globalize-1.1.2/dist/globalize/unit.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/jquery-validation-1.15.1/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/jquery-validation-unobtrusive-3.2.6/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive-3.2.4/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/jquery-validation-globalize-1.0.0/jquery.validate.globalize.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script src="/Content/bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes from the fact that the console.log appends an item inside the `arguments` which is `undefined`.

I corrected the bug by:

1. **Removing** `, console.log("JSONs loaded")`
2. **Amending** `return (typeof result === 'undefined' ? null : result[0]);` **by** `return result[0];`

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is related to your slicing... There's a case where you return `null`, which is what `Globalize.load` is complaining about (it expects a plain object, e.g., `{}`, but instead it's getting `null`).

Comment: I have found the issue, I had to remove the line , `console.log("JSONs loaded")` BUT the issue remains, I keep triggering this error "JavaScript runtime error: E_INVALID_PAR_TYPE: Invalid `value` parameter (null). a string expected."

Comment: For which urls your response is `undefined`? I think if you use `return (typeof result === 'undefined' ? {} : result[0]);` you would bypass the issue, this is at least useful to assert the error is happening there, then you can revert and find which url isn't returning the json.