# CLDR/Globalize: slice JSON array: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: internationalization, jquery-globalize, cldr

We are trying to use [cldr](https://github.com/rxaviers/cldrjs)/[globalize](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize);

an exception is triggered while loading 13 CLDR' json files (like likelySubtags.json).

It seems that the size of the 'arguments' is 14 (instead of 13) which triggers the exception "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

They are several examples using the same 'JavaScript' code and it doesn't seem that people complain; see [A](https://github.com/rxaviers/cldrjs/issues/45), [B](https://gist.github.com/pparadis/d8643555f5ba11bb824c60094745f4b1), [C](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_1/Guide/Common/DevExtreme_Packages/), [D](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T416777) and [E](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32753888/jquery-globalize-setup-using-plain-javascript-uncaught-error/33278559#33278559)

Do you need further info? Do you need more code? Just let me know

---

[image: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined]

**JavaScript, load cldr data, set locale to 'en'**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863853/using-jquery-globalize-with-mvc-5
  // download json files on https://github.com/unicode-cldr?page=2
  // how to setup globalize, cldr and json data: http://johnnyreilly.github.io/globalize-so-what-cha-want

  var locale = 'en'; // TODO: manage the localization based on user preferences (browser)

  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586551/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-validation-with-different-culture
  $.when(
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/plugins/cldr-core-30.0.2/supplemental/likelySubtags.json"),
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/plugins/cldr-numbers-full-30.0.2/main/" + locale + "/numbers.json"),
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/plugins/cldr-core-30.0.2/supplemental/numberingSystems.json"),
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/plugins/cldr-core-30.0.2/supplemental/plurals.json"),
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/plugins/cldr-core-30.0.2/supplemental/ordinals.json"),
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/plugins/cldr-numbers-full-30.0.2/main/" + locale + "/currencies.json"),
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/plugins/cldr-core-30.0.2/supplemental/currencyData.json"),
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/plugins/cldr-dates-full-30.0.2/main/" + locale + "/ca-gregorian.json"),
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/plugins/cldr-dates-full-30.0.2/main/" + locale + "/timeZoneNames.json"),
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/plugins/cldr-core-30.0.2/supplemental/timeData.json"),
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/plugins/cldr-core-30.0.2/supplemental/weekData.json"),
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/plugins/cldr-dates-full-30.0.2/main/" + locale + "/dateFields.json"),
      $.getJSON("/Scripts/plugins/cldr-units-full-30.0.2/main/" + locale + "/units.json"),
      console.log("JSONs loaded")
      ).then(function () {
        console.log("start slicing");
        return [].slice.apply(arguments, [0]).map(function (result) {
          console.log("slicing done");
          return result[0];
        });
      }).then(Globalize.load).then(function () {
        Globalize.locale(locale);
        console.log("Locale set to " + locale);
      }).then(console.log("LOADED EVERYTHING"));


});
```

**HTML , load the javascripts**

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>StratEx | Project management</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE">
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="/Scripts/plugins/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="/Content/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="/Content/bootstrap-3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="/Content/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="/Content/themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script type="application/javascript" async="" defer="" src="https://by2.uservoice.com/t2/ID/web/ID/track.js?_=TIMESTAMP&amp;s=1&amp;c=__uvSessionData0&amp;d=HASH"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="//widget.uservoice.com/CODE.js"></script><script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
  <script
    src="/Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/cldrjs-0.4.7/dist/cldr.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/cldrjs-0.4.7/dist/cldr/event.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/cldrjs-0.4.7/dist/cldr/supplemental.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/globalize-1.1.2/dist/globalize.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/globalize-1.1.2/dist/globalize/number.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/globalize-1.1.2/dist/globalize/plural.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/globalize-1.1.2/dist/globalize/message.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/globalize-1.1.2/dist/globalize/currency.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/globalize-1.1.2/dist/globalize/date.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/globalize-1.1.2/dist/globalize/relative-time.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/globalize-1.1.2/dist/globalize/unit.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/jquery-validation-1.15.1/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/jquery-validation-unobtrusive-3.2.6/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive-3.2.4/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/jquery-validation-globalize-1.0.0/jquery.validate.globalize.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/plugins/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script src="/Content/bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra  `console.log("JSONs loaded")` which triggers the exception as a 14th item is included inside 'arguments'